# PyBluez installation error in linux mint

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth, installation, pybluez

I downloaded the zip folder from pybluez github account and then extracted it.
After going to the directory of pybluex-master, in Terminal, I type
**python setup.py install** 
then, i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, Extension
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

please help me in this, how do i solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try the follwings

Python 2.x:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

Python 3.x

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```